# How to show data in dashboard

Tags: outsystems, lowcode

I have a dashboard, which shows the total count of four containers. for this, I'm having four  aggregates which return totalcount and the label as shown below

[image]

and in the dashboard, showing up the four data as below

[image]

and for each expression value i'm using GetLarvaeDetails.List.Current.CountSum, GetPupaeDetails.List.Current.CountSum...

My question is, I'm making four query calls and rendering it in the dashboard. Is there a way to make one query call which returns a single table with all data and render it via looping like we do in angular ngFor?

Update#1:
I have created a aggregate as shown below and now it returns as a table. How to render it on the dashboard page?

[image]

Update#2:

So here if I use the expression value as `GetContainerReport.List.Current.CountSum`, it's not working. How to show only the particular count?

[image]

Comment: Your Update#2 expression will work fine when you build the Count blocks within a list that iterates over `GetContainerReport.List`.

Comment: So, I need a list and for each list item, I need to put the whole container?

Comment: Tried that, but the list is always taking up the full space and every item is coming in the next row. Here the items are in column wise

Comment: You should be able to fix that using css styling /  changing the tag into a span, if you use traditional ui you should set the line seperator to `none` as well.

Comment: As Mark Baijens commented, a list widget will solve your problem. Just make sure to keep the order the same if you have different icons. :) You can calculate fields in your aggregate to help with dynamic scenarios too (i.e. CSS classes, icon URLs etc)

Comment: Is this a react application or a traditional one? I have an example ready here for a react application if this is a traditional one, please have a look [**here**](https://success.outsystems.com/Documentation/How-to_Guides/Front-End/How_to_show_records_side_by_side_in_a_List_Record_widget).

Comment: Its a reactive application. Will try to manipulate the css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `List widget` with a `List Item` widget inside. Then you add the CSS below.

```
.list .list-item {
    float: left;
}
```

[image]

It will generate this result:
[image]

You can add more properties to the list returned from the aggregate (i.e.: color, icon name) and CSS to make each item look like you need them to look